# Use multiple Redis servers in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am using `Sidekiq` to process background jobs into one of our 
Rails project. We want to use a different Redis server located at different location to sepearate out `ReportDB` with other background processing job.

According to Sidekiq config wiki we can configure like

*config/initializers/sidekiq.rb*

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
   config.redis = { :url => 'redis://redis.example.com:7372/12', :namespace => 'mynamespace' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
   config.redis = { :url => 'redis://redis.example.com:7372/12', :namespace => 'mynamespace' }
end
```

But how can I initialise connection to multiple redis server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidekiq 2 doesn't support multiple Redis servers, upgrade to sidekiq 3 which released just today and adds the new client sharding feature that you need.

From: [Sidekiq 3 Release Note](http://www.mikeperham.com/2014/03/28/sidekiq-3-0/)

> **Client Sharding**
>
> Sidekiq 2.x has a scalability limit: one Redis server. In practice the
>   limit is greater than 5000 jobs per second on good hardware so to most
>   it wasn’t a big deal but some of the more intense Sidekiq users were
>   hitting that limit. An updated (Sidekiq 3) Sidekiq::Client API allows
>   you to specify a Redis connection pool to use, rather than assuming
>   the Sidekiq.redis global pool previously, allowing you to target
>   different types of jobs to different Redis servers. Now you can scale
>   Sidekiq to infinity and beyond!
>
> The API is almost entirely backwards compatible: **the only breaking
>   change is in client-side middleware**. See the [upgrade notes](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/3.0-Upgrade.md) for more
>   detail.

===

Also take a look at the answer for - [Work with two separate redis instances with sidekiq?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19886023/545870)