# Is it possible to run multiple Sidekiq processes with multiple threads on separate servers, and distribute jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I would like to run multiple servers, each running a single Sidekiq process with multiple threads. My product issues several types of jobs, but one type of job often takes a long time and puts a heavy load on the server's CPU and memory.

When this happens, the job server goes down, making it impossible to run other types of jobs. Therefore, I would like to run high-load jobs and other jobs on separate servers while also improving job processing.

Is it possible to do this with Sidekiq?
If so, how can I allocate Sidekiq servers for each job?
I am using ActiveJob with Sidekiq, and both Rails and Sidekiq are up to date.

Comment: Sidekiq jobs usually attach to a Redis instance. It's possible to have multiple Redis instances attached and tell each job which instance to run on.

Comment: But you haven't posted any code. Start by posting your active_job and sidekiq setup info

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22720019/1880203

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19886023/1880203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use host-specific queues, a technique documented on my blog. You create the job in a queue named after the hostname of the CPU-heavy machine:

```
queue_as 'big-dude.example.com'
```

these two are equivalent but `set` allows you to dynamically retarget the job from its default queue.

```
SomeJob.set(queue: 'big-dude.example.com').perform_later(...)
```

And then you'll start Sidekiq running on each machine, listening to its own host queue:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q `hostname` -q default ...
```

Viola!

https://www.mikeperham.com/2013/11/13/advanced-sidekiq-host-specific-queues/